# Change single product summary location When using WooCommerce product add-ons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am trying to change the order of my single product summary for a product add-on. Currently the add-on is located before the quantity selector and add to cart. I want the add-on to be after the quantity selector but before the addto cart button.

i know i have to do something along these lines.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_before_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_before_single_add_to_cart', 90 );
```

Comment: You should better update your question with all related code, as this is very specific and with your actual question code nobody can give you a working answer.

Comment: Just [override templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)